# Read hh:mm:ss in excel file using c#

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, time

I have a excel file contain hour:minute:second (example:**12:20:00**) 
I set format cells is hh:mm:ss in custom catelogy.
I am using C# to read hour:minute:second in this file.
But I received a string contain **"12/30/1899 12:20:00"**

Why? Can anybody answer?
How to resolve this problem?

My code:

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtFileExcelCapture.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
    using (OleDbDataReader rows = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rows.Read())
        {
            var nameChannel = rows[0];
            string HMS = rows[1].ToString();//Result is "12/30/1899 12:20:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank
Quang

Comment: you can use split to get time from this datetime field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can resolve my problem using following code

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(rows[1].ToString());
string HMS = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}",dt);
```

but I don't understand , 
Why contain in excel file is different string in C#?.

Answer (score 1):

Format hh:mm:ss is considered as DateTime field in excel, so when you read it in c#, instead of string you get a DateTime object. And since DateTime object also has date with it, even if not specified, ToString() function provides complete date and time converted to string. Try this to solve your problem:

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtFileExcelCapture.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
    using (OleDbDataReader rows = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rows.Read())
        {
            var nameChannel = rows[0];
            string HMS = (rows[1] as DateTime).TimeOfDay.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Format cell value using `String.Format`. When you read from excel it contains `DateTime` value so format as per you requirement.

```
String.Format("HH:mm:ss",cellValue);
```

In your case use as below to get only time part from cell.

```
rows[1].ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I can resolve my problem using following code <br/> DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(rows[2].ToString());
                            string HMS = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}",dt);<br/> but I don't understand , Why contain in excel file is different string in C#?.

Answer (score 0):

Only add a new step! 
If you receive "12/30/1899 12:20:00", then add at the end .Split(' ')[1] and this will return "12:20:00".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double d = double.Parse(workSheet.Cells[1, 1].value(););
DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is interpreted as `DateTime`-Object. Simply parse it as such and call `datetime.ToLongTimeString()`

The reason why you get a date with year 1899 is that C# is interpreting the value as time and treating it like a `DateTime` object. But since there is no date privided, he takes the earliest date possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the cell there was no information about the date, so c# filled it with [the day 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_0)

What you should do is use

```
String.Format("HH:mm:ss",cellValue);
```

or

```
DateTime time;
time.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```